# Preemption during spin_lock

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

The linux kernel spin_lock implementation disable the preemption by invoking preempt_disable(). In my kernel configuration CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set. Since the interrupts are not disabled during spin_lock interrupt handler can call schedule(). Can anybody please point out the code where the scheduler is not schedule another process since it has acquired a spin_lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interrupt handlers are *not* allowed to call `schedule()`.

Comment: Since schedule() is not allowed in interrupt handler how does round robin type of scheduling is implemented in linux kernel. i.e. Who calls the scheduler so often. In entry_32.S it calls scheduler only if CONFIG_PREEMPT is defined.

Comment: @user1428099: The scheduler may be called upon returning to userspace, including if the kernel was entered from userspace to service an interrupt.